# Bootstrap align icons to leftside and text to center on a top bar

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap CDN on a website where I am trying to align the icons to the left side with logo and centre the text on a top bar. Is there a simple method to get it done?

[Top bar picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaacI.jpg)

```
<div class="topbar clearfix"> 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
                <div class="social">
                    <a href="#" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>              
                    <a href="#" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Google Plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Youtube"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Pinterest"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
                </div><!-- end social -->
            </div><!-- end left -->
            <div class="col-md-8 text-right">
                <p>
                    Интернет-магазин производителя фитоламп и промышленного освещения &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <strong><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></strong> <a href="tel:+74991000000">+7(499) 100-00-00 </a>
                </p>
            </div><!-- end left -->
        </div><!-- end row -->
    </div><!-- end container -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use

```
 class="container-fluid"
```

and adjust the col-md-4  ..  to the value you really need